# android with out using google cloud

Tags: android-notifications

how to get `Notification` with out using `google cloud` . i thought of running a thread in back ground service and update the `Notification` but how i can i do it.pls help me out thanks in advance

```
public class BackgroundThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        List<InvoiceDetail> invoiceDetails = JsonReader.getInvoice();
        if (invoiceDetails.size() > 0) {
            NotificationManager nfman = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            int notifyID = 1;
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    LoginActivity.this).setContentTitle("WORK ASSIGNED")
                    .setContentText("You've received new messages.");
            builder.setContentText("hai");
            nfman.notify(1, builder.build());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public class Notifier extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    SharedPreferences sPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("loginData", 0);
    String id = sPrefs.getString("id", "default value");
    String userss = sPrefs.getString("user", "default value");
    String pass = sPrefs.getString("pass", "default value");
    if (id.trim().length() > 0) {
        List<NotifierDetail> subjects = DataBase.notificationMethod(id);
        if (subjects.size() > 0) {
            User user = new User();
            user.setUserName(userss);
            user.setPassWord(pass);
            User users = DataBase.login(user);
            BaseConstants.user = users;
            for (NotifierDetail sub : subjects) {
                NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Notification notification = new Notification(
                        R.drawable.logo, " Notification Today",
                        System.currentTimeMillis());
                notification.defaults=Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
                notification.defaults=Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
                DataBase.updateNotificationMethod(sub.getId());
                notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                Intent in = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                        in, 0);
                CharSequence name = "Notification";
                CharSequence mess = name + " about " + sub.getSubject();
                notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, name, mess, pi);
                nm.notify(0, notification);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notifier.class);
    sendBroadcast(i);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
      getBaseContext(), 0, i, 0);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0000, 60000,
      pendingIntent);